# Rounded corner image view with a custom view

Tags: android, kotlin, android-imageview, android-custom-view

I currently am trying to make a project which does not use any libraries. Now, I wanted to use a round image many times I can't just do this:

```
<CardView>
   <ImageView/>
</CardView>
```

every time. So, I decided to make a custom class for it. This is my class:

```kotlin
class RoundedImageView : AppCompatImageView {

    constructor(context: Context, attributeSet: AttributeSet) : super(context, attributeSet) {
        init(attributeSet)
    }

    constructor(context: Context) : super(context) {
        init(null);
    }

    private fun init(attributeSet: AttributeSet?) {
        if (attributeSet == null) return

        val typedArray: TypedArray =
            context.obtainStyledAttributes(attributeSet, R.styleable.RoundedImageView, 0, 0)
        try {
            val bitmapDrawable : BitmapDrawable? = drawable as? BitmapDrawable

            val cornerRadius = typedArray.getDimension(R.styleable.RoundedImageView_cornerRadius,0F)

            bitmapDrawable?.bitmap?.let { getRoundedCornerBitmap(it, cornerRadius) }
        }finally {
            typedArray.recycle()
        }
    }

    private fun getRoundedCornerBitmap(bitmap: Bitmap, pixels: Float) {
        val output = Bitmap.createBitmap(
            bitmap.width, bitmap
                .height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
        )
        val canvas = Canvas(output)
        val color = -0xbdbdbe
        val paint = Paint()
        val rect = Rect(0, 0, bitmap.width, bitmap.height)
        val rectF = RectF(rect)
        val roundPx = pixels.toFloat()
        paint.isAntiAlias = true
        canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0)
        paint.color = color
        canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint)
        paint.xfermode = PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN)
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint)
        setImageBitmap(bitmap)
    }
}
```

But, that does not seem to work. This is what I get as a result:
[image]

And, this the code I used for it:

```
<com.sambhav2358.facebookclone.customviews.RoundedImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
```

I am not even sure whether the code reaches that method or not

---

PS: Dont mark it as duplicate because I tried every thing here but none of them seem to work. Even that method `getRoundedCornerBitmap` is taken from a answer but that won't work.

Comment: You can use drawable resource. I'm suggesting this as a comment, if it's relevant to your usecase let me know I'll post how

Comment: I am not sure abt what u r saying. U can post an answer

Comment: Why not the standard ShapeableImageView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you are not drawing on the `view`'s canvas, you've to override `onDraw` to draw anything on the `view`'s canvas. And, as you just want to make your image circular from the corners, you don't need `PorterDuff` for this. You can just clip a rounded rect from the `canvas` and it would be suffice for your use case.

You don't have to manually override each constructor of the `AppCompatImageView`, You can use the `@JvmOverloads` annotation to override every constructor of the `java` class in `kotlin`.

Use `withStyledAttributes` extension function of core-ktx to access `attributeSet`

`init` block can be used to execute code just after the `primary constructor`.

Don't do object allocation inside of `onDraw`, reuse expensive objects like `paint` and `path` as much as possible.

Keeping above points in mind, your class can be changed like this

```
class RoundedImageView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet,
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : AppCompatImageView(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {
    val path = Path()
    var cornerRadius: Float = 0f

    init {
        context.withStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.RoundedImageView) {
            cornerRadius = getDimension(R.styleable.RoundedImageView_cornerRadius, 0F)
        }
    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {
        val corners = floatArrayOf(
            cornerRadius,
            cornerRadius,
            cornerRadius,
            cornerRadius,
            cornerRadius,
            cornerRadius,
            cornerRadius,
            cornerRadius
        )

        path.addRoundRect(
            0f,
            0f,
            width.toFloat(),
            height.toFloat(),
            corners,
            Path.Direction.CW
        )

        canvas?.clipPath(path)
        super.onDraw(canvas)
    }
}
```

Now, it can be used like this

```
<com.sambhav2358.facebookclone.customviews.RoundedImageView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        app:cornerRadius="70dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
        />
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you try below code and refer official [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/imageview/ShapeableImageView) for more details.

```
<com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivNotificationIcon"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_45sdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_45sdp"
         android:backgroundTint="#EEF3F7"
        android:contentDescription="@string/image_description"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"   
 app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/ShapeAppearanceOverlay.App.CornerSize50Percent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/slider" />
```

and add this style in you style.xml/theme.xml

```
 <style name="ShapeAppearanceOverlay.App.CornerSize50Percent" parent="">
 <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
        <item name="cornerSize">50%</item>
        <item name="backgroundTint">@android:color/white</item>        </style>
```

As per your requirement you will add items in the custom style.

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to mention it. But, I dont wanna use that view. My question says that I want a custom view. But, upvoted it

Answer (score -1):

You can create a Drawable resource as follows, rounded_corners.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
    <solid android:color="#00000000"/>
</shape>
```

and then you can use it as follows:

```
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners"/>
```

And this will create any ImageView with rounded corners. You can control the radius and everything you need in the rounded_corners.xml
I've created it transparent so you can place any image you wish in the ImageView.

Comment: I want a custom view. My question has that mentioned clearly

Comment: Well, it seemed to me you decided to make your own class as an attempt to create a round corners view. That's why I also asked in the comments if it's relevant. Either way, if it's not then I guess just ignore this answer